# How to create a mesh from an alpha mask?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl

I want to create a mesh in Unity o using OpenGL using an alpha mask, like the simple one I show below.  So I can `hide` part of virtual object that will be behind the mesh.
[image: Alpha Mask]
Is it possible? Is there any easier method to hide part of a virtual object?

Answer (score 0):

“Stencil testing” is what you want. Look up how to do it in whatever game engine / graphics API you are using.